# Retrieve the index of item in list before insertion within Stateful Batch Apex Class

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous

I have a batch class that implements the following headers `Database.Batchable<Map<String, Object>>, Database.Stateful` . Within the `DocumentParser` class, I am creating a `Map Object` that is inserted into a list that is called `ListMapIdtoSObj`.

I need to be able to know ahead of time the exact index where this map object will be inserted.

In my code, I am using `this.ListMapIdtoSObj.size() - 1`  to know the index that this record will be inserted into within the overall list.

The issue with this approach is that because this is a batch class, the other execute methods are also running asynchronously.

With that being said, I am trying to figure out how within my code I can retrieve the exact index where this record lives within the overall list during execution.

Below is my code for reproducing this logic.

Batch Class

```
 * @description       : 
 * @author            : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
 * @group             : 
 * @last modified on  : 08-06-2022
 * @last modified by  : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
**/
global class TfIdfMain implements Database.Batchable<Map<String, Object>>, Database.Stateful {

    DocumentParser dp;
    List<Map<String,Object>> recordsToAnalyze = new List<Map<String,Object>>();
    Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
    Integer batchSize;

    global TfIdfMain(Map<String,Object> params)
    {
        this.params = params;
        this.recordsToAnalyze = (List<Map<String,Object>>) params.get('recordToAnalyze');
        this.batchSize = (Integer) params.get('batchSize');
        this.dp = new DocumentParser();
    }

    

    global Iterable<Map<String, Object>> start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

        return  this.recordsToAnalyze;
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Map<String, Object>> records)
    {

        this.dp.parseSobjects(records);




    }    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {

        System.debug('Inside TfIdfMain Finish');
        params.put('DocumentParser', dp);
        TfIdfMainMatches b = new TfIdfMainMatches(this.params); 
        Database.executeBatch(b, this.batchSize);

    }    
}
```

Document Parser Class

```
/**
 * @description       : 
 * @author            : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
 * @group             : 
 * @last modified on  : 08-06-2022
 * @last modified by  : ChangeMeIn@UserSettingsUnder.SFDoc
**/
public class DocumentParser 
{

    //This variable will hold all terms of each document in an array.
    private List<String[]> termsDocsArray = new List<String[]>();
    private List<String> allTerms = new List<String>(); //to hold all terms
    private List<double[]> tfidfDocsVector = new List<double[]>();
    private List<String> tfidfDocsVectorNames = new List<String>();

    
    // objects to Return
    public List<Map<Id, Object>> ListMapIdtoSObj = new List<Map<Id, Object>>();
    public Map<Id, Object> MapIdtoSObjToReturn = new Map<Id, Object>();


    public void parseSobjects(List<Map<String, Object>> recordsToAnalyze )
{

    String[] allStrings = new List<String>();

    Integer sizeOfList = recordsToAnalyze.size();

    System.debug('Size of List ' + String.valueOf(sizeOfList) );

    Integer i = 0;
    for (Map<String, Object> recordToAnalyze : recordsToAnalyze) 
    {
        

        String str = (String) recordToAnalyze.get('fieldToAnalyze');
        Id  sObjId = (Id) recordToAnalyze.get('recordId');

        allStrings.add(str);


            String sobjectType = sObjId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

            Map<Id, Object> mapIdtoObj = new Map<Id, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> mapObj = new Map<String, Object>{
                'ID'  => sObjId, 
                'term' => str,
                'Index' => this.ListMapIdtoSObj.size() - 1 ,
                'SObject Type' => sobjectType,
                'ListOfMatches' => new List<Map<String, Object>>()
            };

            mapIdtoObj.put(sObjId, mapObj);

            this.ListMapIdtoSObj.add(mapIdtoObj);
            this.MapIdtoSObjToReturn.put(sObjId, mapObj);
            i++;
        }


    for (String str : allStrings) 
    {
            String[] tokenizedTerms = Ngrams.ngrams(3, str);
            // String[] tokenizedTerms = str.replaceAll('[\\W&&[^\\s]]', '').split('\\W+');   //to get individual terms
            for(String term : tokenizedTerms)   //avoid duplicate entries
            {
                if(!allTerms.contains(term))
                {
                    allTerms.add(term);
                }
            }
            termsDocsArray.add(tokenizedTerms);
            tfidfDocsVectorNames.add(str);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Note that the `execute` calls are guaranteed to be made in order one after the other if only a single batchable is running. Does that simplify the problem for you?

Comment: @KeithC that solves the issue!